# Can't click the link with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

This code works fine on another site. But it's not working for [this site](http://momond.ml). Please help me find the cause, the error...

The code must fulfill a click on one of the ad units.
Ad units are generated in `index.html` with JavaScript. After loading page pictures and links are displayed. I need to perform a click on one of them.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://momond.ml')
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'xpicw.top')]").click()
browser.quit()
```

`xpicw.top` is a part of link ad units links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link located inside an `iframe`. To click it you should switch to that frame first:

```
browser.switch_to_frame(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[starts-with(@class,"tblock_")]'))
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'xpicw.top')]").click()
```